# 100% width user's profile cover photo?

Tags: usability, design, users, responsive

I just wonder whether anyone or services allows a user to have a 100% width profile cover photo like [these](https://dribbble.com/shots/1696992-Responsive-Dashboard) [examples](https://dribbble.com/shots/1354247-Soflee-profile) I found on Dribbble. I want to try to put this feature into my one of my projects.

What if the screen is too wide (like 27 inches) and the photo resolution is not good enough? Is there any best practice for this feature?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking here. Are you asking how to do it, or what the UX implications of this is, or...?

Comment: I mean that is it a good practice to enable this feature for user ? On smaller screens, laptop or tablet, it may looks good. However, when the screen is too wide then if the photo's resolution is not good enough then it'll not be nice anymore.

Comment: Not looking nice is relative. Twitter does just that with their user's images, and when it exceeds the resolution, it becomes pixelized, but still maintains a certain sense of beauty: www.twitter.com

Comment: Thanks, I just tried upload an average size header photo and somehow, one my large screen, it still look acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your audience.

Professional designers?  Yeah, they'll make sure the graphic is awesome.  Professional artists with management and social media teams?  Of course they will.

Your average user?  Absolutely not.  They will grab whatever photo they usually use or some random one from profilephotoplacewithglitter.com and be done.

If you want your site to look good, don't depend on the user for anything.

Source: My facebook friends.